# Possible to round numbers to the hundreds, thousands, etc. using Python 3's number formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, formatting, seaborn

## Specific Issue

I am trying to print out the numbers on top of the cells in a `seaborn` heatmap.  For instance, something like:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt=",")
```

(This is taken directly from [`seaborn`'s documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap), adjusted to be Python 3-friendly.  So if you import `seaborn`, you can run the same example out of the box.)

---

This generates a fairly respectable figure like the one below:

[image: heatmap, not quite ideal]

However, I would like to see the numbers rounded to the nearest ***hundreds***.  In other words, I want to see numbers like 171 written as 200, and 315 written as 300, etc.

---

## Ideas

Under the hood, `seaborn` is really just `matplotlib`.  I can use `matplotlib`'s [`text` methods](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html).

`matplotlib`'s text relies upon Python 3's [text formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html), which has convenient ways to round ***to the right of the decimal***, by doing things like `.2` to round to the hundred***ths***, but I cannot find anything to round in the other direction.

---

I could simply round the numbers before I push them to the plot, but that will actually alter the plot data itself, which I'd rather avoid.  Therefore, I would like to leaving the ***underlying numbers that I pass to the plot unaltered***, while still being able to print things nicely.

---

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to find a clever way to format things.  Is there a way?

Thanks!

## Update

I dug further into [`seaborn`'s code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/76655613b5e87e4908f125ebfcc0f77c25772100/seaborn/matrix.py), trying to understand why La Rooy's clever solution below did not work for me.

The relevant line within the `seaborn` code is:

```
val = ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)
```

---

However, for this to work, I would need to be able to alter my `pandas` dataframe column, which means that I'd need to be able to adjust the column of `nd.array` elements.

It seems that there is [not yet any underlying `.__format__` method for a `numpy` array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5543), but there is an effort to create one.

So, I'm for the moment going to chase this issue no further, and hope that once things sort themselves out, I'll be able to take La Rooy's solution and things should "work".

Once that happens, the solution would be:

```
>>> class rndarray(np.ndarray):
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         return np.ndarray.__format__(int(round(self, -2)), spec)
... 
>>> df['<col_of_interest>'] = map(rndarray, df['<col_of_interest.'])
```

or, if that didn't work, then:

```
>>> df['<col_of_interest>'].values = map(rndarray, df['<col_of_interest.'].values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subclass of `int` and define `__format__` however you like.

```
>>> class rint(int):
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         return int.__format__(int(round(self, -2)), spec)
... 
>>> raw_data = [111, 22222, 33333]
>>> data = map(rint, raw_data)
>>> [format(x, ',') for x in data]
['100', '22,200', '33,300']
```

Or equivalently for floats

```
>>> class rfloat(float):
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         return float.__format__(round(self, -2), spec)
... 
>>> raw_data = [111.11, 22222.22, 33333.33]
>>> data = map(rfloat, raw_data)
>>> spec = ',.0f'
>>> [format(x, spec) for x in data]
['100', '22,200', '33,300']
```

Edit:
This more hacky solution leverages the `val = ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)` line. Of course this may break if the implementation changes.

```
class Fmt(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Fmt(str.__add__(self, other))
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Fmt(str.__add__(other, self))
    def format(self, *args):
        return str.format(self, *(int(round(x, -2)) for x in args))

ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt=Fmt(","))
```

Better would be to be able to pass a `Formatter()` instead of just a `fmt` string.

Comment: Great idea!!  That actually didn't seem to work with `seaborn`, as is.  But I suspect that's because I need to look under the hood further to see how seaborn is actually calling the format functions.  Regardless of how it works under the hood, this gets me on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: Still didn't work, but I updated the original question with further details explaining the issue.  Your methodology is dead on, IMHO, but np.ndarray is not ready to partake in your elegance, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
'{:.0f}00'.format(yourNumber / 100.0)
```

for every cell solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @B0dz1o, but it does not.  Again, the problem is that the parameter `fmt` accepts a simple text value.  So, I could pass `'{:.0f}00'`, perhaps, but there's no way I could ask my number to be divided by 100 ahead of time.  (I don't even think I could pass that string... `fmt` seems to accept ***only*** the part inside the curly braces.